# Publishing new GitHub page

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a site published at username.github.io and want to publish a different one.  How do I replace it with a project in a new repository?  I switched my default file in the new one to gh-pages and that published it under username.github.io/Repository but now when I push changes they go to the master branch and don't change on the published site.  Confused and just looking for easiest way to replace my old site with the new one, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A [User page](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/) (`<username>.github.io`) differs from a Project page (`http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>`): its pages can only be published from `master`.

For the former (User Page repo), all you have to do is:

- checkout the master branch
- delete your files and commit
- add your new files (for the new site) and commit.

That will replace your existing User page web site.

> I switched my default file in the new one to `gh-pages` and that published it under `username.github.io/Repository`

That is a project page, and putting those files on master won't make them published on a User Page repo.